# Underscore.js - Map Array of key/value pairs to an Object - One liner

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've been going through the [underscore docs](http://underscorejs.org/) but I can't seem to find a method (or nested method call) to do the following transformation:

Let's say I have the following Javascript array:

```
 [{ "name" : "sEcho", "value" : 1},{ "name" : "iColumns", "value" : 12}, ... ]
```

And I need to transform it into the following object:

```
 {
      sEcho: 1,
      iColumns: 12,
      ...
 }
```

I'm using underscore.js for a reason so it *must* be a one liner.

Comment: One line? `_.map(arr,function(v,o){o={};return o[v.name]=v.value,o });` Not sure if there's a shorter way to do it...

Comment: @elclanrs That would create an array of objects. You only want one object.

Comment: @AaditMShah: Right, I misunderstood then...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since nobody has posted this as an answer, I'm posting it because I think it is better than [Jan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802471/31671). It's shorter, and cleaner without the inline function.

```
_.object(_.pluck(data, 'name'), _.pluck(data, 'value'));
```

Comment: AFAICS underscore does not explicitly guarantee any order of `pluck`'s and `map`'s result, so even if this works in current browsers, I wouldn't rely on it. Imagine how hard it would be to track down a bug where values are assigned to the wrong keys.

Comment: What you say is true, however I will just note that the OP did not explicitly request the same order.

Comment: I didn't worry about the order of the key-value pairs in the map (AFAIK, there's now guarantee about that in JS anyway), but rather values being assigned to the wrong keys. Sometime, in some browser, plucking the names *might* return another order than plucking the values, which would completely mess up your data and return e.g. `{sEcho:12, iColumns:1}` instead of the expected result. That's why I would prefer to do the key-value mapping in a single operation like `reduce` or `map`

Comment: @peterp I see. In this case though, the `pluck`, `map`, and `object` functions are all operating on arrays, where order is guaranteed so there is no problem.

Comment: agreed, the current implementation of underscore.js is safe in this regard; but without explicit guarantee the implementation might be different in future versions. I was definitely wrong about "some browser", it would need "some other version of underscore.js" to break the code, thanks for the heads-up. Feel free to call me paranoid, but I'd still prefer not to rely on the order, though. :)

Comment: A healthy paranoia is always a good thing. :-) I think Underscore would have to work really hard to mess this up though, since we never give pass it any objects to work with.

Answer (score 60):

Variation on [Sza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802319/499214), using the "array of pairs" signature of `_.object`:

```
_.object(_.map(data, function(x){return [x.name, x.value]}))
```

Comment: Nice! Even save a few keystrokes if you're using typescript ;)

`_.object(_.map(data, (x) => {return [x.name, x.value]}))`

Comment: @parliament or coffeescript :-)

Comment: Also, Sza's example would work without the zip (since object takes either a single array of name/val pairs or two different arrays). So you could do `_.object(_pluck(data, 'name'), _.pluck(data, 'value'))`

Comment: Speaking of other languages, the clearest might be using a comprehension in CS: `_.object([o.name, o.value] for o in data)`

Comment: it could be clearer with the `_.chain` function : https://gist.github.com/ablanchet/f8b9c3ece0812ebf3f3c

Comment: Downside of the pluck version is that it iterates through the data twice (pluck/pluck) and then again to generate the result (object): the map solution iterates once through data (map), and then once through the result (object).

Answer (score 27):

This should do it:

```
_.reduce(array, function(o, v){
    o[v.name] = v.value;
    return o;
}, {});
```

As a one-liner (you are kidding me, right?):

```
_.reduce(array,function(a,b){a[b.name]=b.value;return a},{});
```

Comment: Why are you summing the `b.value` values? Why not a simple `a[b.name] = b.value`?

Comment: @muistooshort I thought it was supposed to sum them, dunno really why xD

Comment: I don't see any summing requested. And if they're trying to be clever with a one-liner (what other reason could there be?) then you might as well be blatant about your hate for the maintainers and throw in a comma operator: `_(a).reduce(function(m, h) { return m[h.name] = h.value, m }, { })`. Heh.

Comment: @muistooshort yeah I guess that was just a brainfart, I have now removed the summing. Btw I used closure compiler to generate the one-liner which prefers semicolon :P

Comment: @muistooshort: i'll be sure to leave a comment 8-)

Comment: This answer is **most performant**, as it requires just one traversal of the original array.

Answer (score 7):

```
var names = _.pluck(data, 'name');
var values = _.pluck(data, 'value');
var result = _.object(_.zip(names, values));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: +1 Although it is interesting to note that one needs 3 separate less-known, kind of specialized methods to do something in same amount of code that one can do using 1 relatively well-known method (reduce).

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have the following JavaScript array:

```
var list = [
    {
         name: "sEcho",
         value: 1
    },
    {
         name: "iColumns",
         value: 12
    },
    ...
];
```

You can convert it into the format you want as follows:

```
var table = _.reduce(list, function (table, item) {
    table[item.name] = item.value;
    return table;
}, {});
```

It's not a one liner, but I don't think you literally meant a one liner. Did you?

Here's a one liner if you really meant a one liner:

```
var t = _.reduce(list, function (t, i) { return t[i.name] = i.value, t; }, {});
```

Yes, others have provided the same answer. However that's only because the answer to your question is so simple.

Answer (score 3):

```
var a =  [{ "name" : "sEcho", "value" : 1},{ "name" : "iColumns", "value" : 12} ];

var o = {}; _.each(a, function(e) { o[e.name] = e.value; });

console.log(o);
// Object {sEcho: 1, iColumns: 12}
```

Answer (score 2):

perfect place to use reduce I think:

`_.reduce(ary, function(memo, obj){ memo[obj["name"]] = obj["value"]; return memo }, {});`

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [{ "name" : "sEcho", "value" : 1},{ "name" : "iColumns", "value" : 12}]
```

ES6

```
_.mapObject( _.indexBy(arr, 'name'), (v) => v.value )
```

ES5

```
_.mapObject( _.indexBy(arr, 'name'), function (v) { return v.value; } )
```

This iterates twice though

Answer (score -1):

A better and easier way, something I stumbled upon.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  
        var obj = {
            Company: "GeeksforGeeks",
            Address: "Noida",
            Contact: "+91 9876543210",
            Email: "abc@gfg.com"
        }
        console.log(_.keys(obj));
    </script>
```

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/underscore-js-_-keys-function/

Comment: This does half of the opposite of what is asked.